# Windows 10 not having an option to create 2.4ghz hotspot

Tags: windows, windows-10, hotspot

Before fresh installing windows 10 I had an option to create 2.4 ghz and 5 ghz hotspot, but after installing windows 10 again there is no option to create 2.4 ghz hotspot! I wonder whether it's a driver not installed or windows has this new feature.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open "Network Connections" in Control Panel.
2. Right click your wireless adapter
3. Select "Properties"
4. Select "Configure"
5. Move to the "Advanced tab"
6. Around half way down there should be an option called "Preferred Band" or something similar. Select 2.4ghz.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Go to Wi-Fi settings
Click on Change Adapter Settings or Network and Sharing options (you can get to it though both)
Click on the Wi-Fi adapter
Click on Configure
Click on Multi Channel Concurrent in Advanced settings
Scroll to Enabled + Hotspot

you should then go back to your Wi-Fi settings and now you will see the 2.4ghz and 5ghz band switcher underneath the password field.